# Jooq Java SpringBoot - Unable to auto generate classes

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I have created one new table in Postgres db & I am trying to auto generate the jooq classes using the below command:

```
java -classpath jooq-3.9.5.jar:jooq-codegen-3.9.5.jar:jooq-meta-3.9.5.jar:postgresql-42.2.2.jar:.org.jooq.util.GenerationTool library.xml
```

But I am getting error as :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class library.xml
```

I have placed the library.xml file in resources folder. I am newbie to jooq, spring boot. Please help how shall I auto generate jooq classes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space in your command between the end of the classpath and the start of the name of the main class that you want to run. As a result, `java` is trying to execute a main class called `library.xml` rather than `org.jooq.util.GenerationTool`. Try the following command instead:

```
java -classpath jooq-3.9.5.jar:jooq-codegen-3.9.5.jar:jooq-meta-3.9.5.jar:postgresql-42.2.2.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool library.xml
```

Note the space before `org.jooq.util.GenerationTool`.